# $\ell_p$ geodesic distance on smooth Riemannian manifold and Logarithmic Sobolev Inequalities

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, measure-concentration

Bear with me, I'm not a professional geometer. Recently, I've been studying Logarithmic Sobolev Inequalities (LSI) for probability distributions on manifolds (e.g as done in works of Bobkvo et al. 1999, Otto et Villani 2000, etc.). Out of curiosity, I'm led to consider the following question (I still have LSIs in mind).

Given $p \in [1,\infty)$ and a smooth finite-dimensional real Riemaniann manifold $M$, when does it make sense (i.e one can do some interesting geometry, etc.) to define a distance

$$d_p(x,y) := \inf_{\omega \in \mathcal C^1([0, 1], M) | \omega(0)=x,\omega(1) = y}\left(\int_0^1\|\dot\omega(t)\|_p^pdt\right)^{1/p} ?
$$
Is there any literature on this ?

## Observation

The case $p=2$, is what is usually done in textbooks, etc.

Comment: For $p>1$ the minimizers have constant speed; so the choice of $p$ makes no difference.

Comment: should say Bear with me

Comment: Oops that's one serious typo. Thanks!

Comment: @AntonPetrunin could you please explain how this is so. Also, note the subscript $p$ in $\|\dot{\omega}(t)\|_p^p$.

Comment: The definition makes perfectly good sense and takes you into the realm of [Finsler geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finsler_manifold).

Comment: @NateEldredge Ah, that's wonderful then. Thanks! I guess my question will then be: Are there any LSIs in FInsler geometry ? I'd guess it hasn't been studied at all.

Comment: I'm not familiar with it myself, but Google for "finsler manifold log sobolev" turns up quite a few hits, including https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.05704 which appears to prove an LSI under some assumptions.  There's been work on LSI in very general settings, e.g. metric measure spaces, so I would have been surprised if it hadn't been addressed at all in Finsler geometry.